# Add an Array of length x to value in key : value hash using Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, key-value

Here is a hash

```
personal_details = {
  name: name,
  dob: dob,
  age: age,
  height: height
}
```

Here is an array

```
puts "What are the name of some of your relatives? (eg. Bob, James, Harry etc)"
relatives = gets().chomp.split(",")
```

Lets say the input for relatives was "Bob, James, Harry".

I want the hash to look like this:

```
personal_details = {
  name: name,
  dob: dob,
  age: age,
  height: height
  relatives: [
         {name: Bob},
         {name: James},
         {name: Harry}
  ]
}
```

The array in the hash is updated based on user input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by initialising relatives as an array:

```
personal_details = {
  name: name,
  dob: dob,
  age: age,
  height: height,
  relatives: []
}
```

Then for each relative, push to the array:

```
relatives = gets().chomp.split(",")
relatives.each do |relative|
  personal_details.relatives.push(name: relative)
end
```

Comment: This worked `personal_details[:relatives].push(name: relative)`

Answer (score 0):

This should work, if I've interpreted the question as intended:

`personal_details[:relatives] = relatives.map{|r| {name: r}}`